# 503 error for long HTTP connections to apache 2.4 on centos 7

Tags: apache-2.4, https, http, centos7, 503-error

I'm running Apache 2.4 (mpm event mode + php-fpm) on CentOS 7. For HTTP requests which  take longer than 60 seconds (whether it's a dynamic PHP page or a static page), exactly after one minute I receive a 503 service unavailable error page. If I access same page through HTTPS protocol, everything seems to be OK. In both cases, PHP scripts continue to run till the end properly, but in former case clients receive an error page and its strongly unpleasant. I guess it maybe is a network related problem or something related to CentOS limitations (SELinux is also off)
Any ideas?

Comment: If you receive a proper HTTP error page I doubt it is network related, it is some specific application (your webserver or a proxy in front of it) that decides there is a timeout and reply like that

Comment: I receive a 503 error page. If its a webserver problem, which Apache configuration should be changed to fix it?

Comment: You would first need to have a look at Apache log files to see precisely what is happening, if the error is generated here, you will see it there. Otherwise configuration files should in in `/etc/apache` or something like that.